# Why does my debug console debug old files that are closed and not the current file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, ide

I am learning VS Code Insiders.  I made 3 files named array.js, array2.js, and maps.js.  For some reason, every time I click the debug icon and click play, the debug console prints array2.js.  I've done everything I can think of, Googling how to clear garbage; restarting the program, closing array2.js, moving array.js to another location, but it's like the editor won't forget it and debug maps.js.  Can someone point me in the right direction so that I can debug whichever file I am working with?

[image: screenshot of maps.js debug console]

[image: screenshot of arrays2 debug console]

Comment: We may need to see your .vscode/launch.json file.

Comment: {
   
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/maps.js" //I added this today trying to help myself 
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/arrays2.js"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Mark I pasted it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this launch.json and let us know if it helps:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${file}"
    }
 ]
}
```

It will use whichever file is active at the time you launch the debug.  While it doesn't directly deal with a caching problem - it is a good place to start in your case.

Comment: I'm glad, I suspected it was something with the launch.json.  Please consider accepting the answer if it helped.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your local Cookies and Cache.
Your browser stores some data, to avoid loading data over and over again.
Click `Ctrl+Shift+Del` while in your browser.
That should do it

Comment: I also tried clearing editor history, but that didn't work either.  :(

Comment: I tried adding a configuration for maps.js to the launch.json file; is this what I have to do for each file I create?